# Laravel 5 search results pagination

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination

I have created some search filters using a textbox and drop downs so when I click the search button i want to use any of these filters to query eloquent relationships.

The search works fine and I get the correct amount of results but the problem lies with the pagination.  When I click on the next page button (or any other page), the result is result and I get everything again.

I know this because I'm not doing a request when the paging is clicked so my question is how do i perform so same query but using the paging?

Here is my controller function

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if(!empty($request)) {

        $products = Product::with(['supplier', 'carrier', 'name']);

        if($request->name) {
            $products = $products->whereHas('Name', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $products = $query->where('Name', $request->name);
            });
        }
        if($request->subtype) {
            $products = $products->whereHas('SubType', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $products = $query->where('SubTypeId', $request->subtype);
            });
        }
        if($request->supplier) {
            $products = $products->whereHas('Supplier', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $products = $query->where('SupplierId', $request->supplier);
            });
        }
        if($request->carrier) {
            $products = $products->whereHas('Carrier', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $products = $query->where('CarrierId', $request->carrier);
            });
        }

        $products = $products->paginate(8);
    }
    else {
        $products = Product::with(['supplier', 'carrier', 'name'])->paginate(8);
    }

    $suppliers = Supplier::all();
    $carriers = Carrier::all();
    $subtypes = SubType::all();

    $options = array(
        'products' => $products,
        'suppliers' => $suppliers,
        'subtypes' => $subtypes,
        'carriers' => $carriers
    );

    return view('products.index')->with($options);
}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem but just a side note: you don't need to do `$products = $query->where(...)`, only `$query->where(...)` is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix it by changing the controller function. I didn't the IF statement

```
$products = Product::with(['supplier', 'carrier', 'name']);

if($request->name) {
    $products = $products->whereHas('Name', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('Name', $request->name);
    });
}
if($request->subtype) {
    $products = $products->whereHas('SubType', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('SubTypeId', $request->subtype);
    });
}
if($request->supplier) {
    $products = $products->whereHas('Supplier', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('SupplierId', $request->supplier);
    });
}
if($request->carrier) {
    $products = $products->whereHas('Carrier', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('CarrierId', $request->carrier);
    });
}

$products = $products->paginate(8);

$suppliers = Supplier::all();
$carriers = Carrier::all();
$subtypes = SubType::all();

$options = array(
    'products' => $products,
    'suppliers' => $suppliers,
    'subtypes' => $subtypes,
    'carriers' => $carriers
);

return view('products.index')->with($options);
```

In my view where I put the pagination link, I replaced

```
{{ $products->links() }}
```

with

```
{{ $products->appends(\Request::except('_token'))->render() }}
```